# perl hash printing the value of a key

Tags: perl, hash, key

the below script stores the key value pairs. Based on the input key given it should retrieve the corresponding value. In below code I am able to see the key value pairs from the first print but when I give one of the keys as an input, it throws an error saying "uninitialized hash".
How to solve this ?

```
...
for my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print "$key = $hash{$key}\n"; 
}
 my $key = <STDIN>;
 print "list is = $hash{$key}\n";
```

Comment: [`perldoc -f chomp`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#chomp)

Comment: FWIW, the "error" is just a warning, and the full warning is "uninitialized hash value", because you tried to interpolate into a string the value of a hash key that does not have a defined value (uninitialized is an unfortunate word choice that is now used mostly for backcompat).

Comment: @Grinnz, Re "*the "error" is just a warning*", So? That the error resulted in a warning and incorrect output rather than an exception doesn't make it any less of an error.

Comment: Even though it is clear what the error was, it would help in the future if you provided in the question both STDOUT and STDERR, as well added printing the `$key`, not just `$hash{$key}`. STDOUT would have suggested the need for `chomp`, as one comment and the accepted answer say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$key` contains the line entered *including the trailing line feed*. Add

```
chomp($key);
```